# Issues Authenticating with AAD using Cypress

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, cypress

I'm trying to write automated tests using Cypress for an application which is authenticated through Azure Active Directory.

I'm following a guide [found on the cypress website](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/azure-active-directory-authentication), and it is successfully loading the login page, entering the password and seems to be successful til the last step - when the  POST token API call fails with an error 400 and including this error message from AAD

> Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests

Some research has indicated that this is due to the "origin" header not being passed, and the header is actually not being sent with the request.

If I modify the `chromeWebSecurity` field in the config, it works for a while, but then randomly and inconsistantly starts failing again

```js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents,
    specPattern: "cypress/e2e/features/*.feature",
    baseUrl: "https://xxxxxxxxx", //My website url
    chromeWebSecurity:true,
    experimentalModifyObstructiveThirdPartyCode:true,
    }
//...
});
```

The login code is copied almost directly from the example in the guide, but I've reproduced it here

```js
function loginViaAAD(username, password) {
    cy.visit('https://xxxxxxxxx')//My website

    // Login to your AAD tenant.
    cy.origin(
      'login.microsoftonline.com',
      {
        args: {
          username,
          password
        },
      },
      ({ username, password }) => {
        cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(username, {
          log: false,
        })
        cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()
        cy.get('input[type="password"]').type(password, {
                    log: false,
                  })
                  cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()
                  cy.contains("Yes").click();
      }
    )
        cy.url().should("contain","https://xxxxxxx"); //My website
    }
```

How can I fix this, why isn't Cypress sending the origin header with the request?

Comment: could you pls help check if you had add redirect URL with SPA platform in Azure AD? https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QrcO.png    and pick up the access token and id token.

Comment: you had `cy.visit('https://xxxxxxxxx')` so the redirect url should be your website url

Comment: Yes the redirect url is set up properly in Azure AD - this works when not under cypress.

Comment: @user2110845 was this ever solved?  I'm seeing the same issue.